# How to get all Google contacts using .NET library and exponential backoff

Tags: google-docs-api

Using the .NET client library to [get all the contacts](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v2/developers_guide_dotnet?csw=1#retrieving_without_query) is normally done like this:

```
Feed<Contact> f = cr.GetContacts();
foreach (Contact e in f.Entries)
{
    // do something with the contact e
}
```

I want to modify this so I can catch 503 errors and re-try the request using exponential backoff.  I understand how to catch the error and do exponential backoff, but am struggling with the syntax to keep looping through all the Entries in order when there is a re-try.  I'm thinking it is something like this:

```
Feed<Contact> f = cr.GetContacts();
try
{
    foreach (Contact e in f.Entries)
    {
        // do something with the contact e
    }
}
catch (GDataRequestException e)
{
    // see if this should be re-tried, and if so repeat position in the foreach loop
}
```

Any help with the structure/syntax would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that helped in my case:

```
this._contactsRequest.Settings.AutoPaging = true;
```

Just set the AutoPaging property in the settings of the ContactsRequest Object to true and all is fine, but the operation needs very long to complete (In my case 250 test contacts).